# Are both halves of a symmetrical FFT result required to generate the original waveform?

Tags: fft

Performing an FFT on a purely real signal produces a symmetrical result. I want to recreate the $50\textrm{ Hz}$ mains hum to actively subtract it from my signal, but:

- are both halves of the FFT result required to do this?
- Is there any drawback to only using one half of a symmetrical FFT result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perfectly use, $X_h[k]$, one half of the **conjugate symmetric** DFT $X_f[k]$ which belongs to a real signal $x[n]$ of length $N$.

Of course in doing so, you must symmetrically pad the half length DFT $X_h[k]$ to the full length DFT $X_f[k]$, which is obviously necessary for an unaliased reconstruction of $x[n]$ from its proper length DFT $X_f[k]$ of length N.

Note that during the creation of the mirrored padded full DFT $X_f[k]$ from the symetric half $X_h[k]$, the first sample $X_h[0]$ is not repeated and the remainig samples $X_h[1]$ to $X_h[M-1]$ are **mirrored** with their **phase** being negated (i.e. they are **conjugated**), where $M$ is the length of the half length DFT $X_h[k]$.

The length $M$ of the half sized DFT $X_h[k]$ is given by the following: If the signal's (or its natural DFT $X_f[k]$'s) length $N$ is **even** then $M= 1 + \frac N 2 = \frac{N+2}{2}$, otherwise, if $N$ is **odd** $M = 1 + \frac{N-1}{2} = \frac{N+1}{2} $.

Also when $N$ is even, the last sample of the half sized DFT, $X_h[M]$ is not repeated, and when $N$ is odd then the last sample $X_h[M]$ is conjugate mirrored in formation of the full length DFT $X_f[k]$, as examplified below Matlab/Octave code:

```
x = [1:8];      % N = 8 , a signal of length N = 8 (even)
X = fft(x,8);   % X[k] is the natural DFT of x[n]
Xh = X(1:5);    % M = (8+2)/2 = 5, also matlab indexing starts from k=1
Xf = [ Xh conj(Xh(end-1:-1:2))];    %N:even => Xh[0] and Xh[5] not repeated
xr = ifft(Xf,8); % reconstruct the original signal from Xf[k]
xr = 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
```

as expected.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise that X[0] does not repeat.

Comment: When you say "you must symmetrically pad the half length DFT to the full length DFT", do you mean fill the rest with 0's or pad the values? ie. If my DFTh is {0,1,0,0}, the DFTf would be {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0} or {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}

Comment: Pad with zero is something else, what I say is pad with **mirrored** samples. So if your DFTh is {0,1,0,0} then the DFTf is {0,1,0,0,**0**,**0**,**1**} where te last three elements are mirrored versions of DFTh. (Note that the first element of DTFh isn't repeated, as I stated in the answer)